# Do l need a comma in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, commas

To me, the following sentence is fine. But my colleague insists that l use a comma after the word "ancient".

- Archeologists discovered a unique, long, broken, ancient (?) Egyptian bronze spear from 5000 years ago.

Comment: If the object is 5,000 years old, it's hardly necessary to include the adjective _ancient_!

Comment: Yes, Kate makes a good point (I didn't intend the pun, but I'll leave it). The more general point is that anything over 3 separate premodifiers is usually seen as cumbersome. This grades into loss of ease of reading, and even clarity ... a Gricean Maxim violation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether there should be a comma depends on whether the spear is ancient **and** Egyptian (that is, old and from Egpyt), or ancient Egyptian (coming from ancient Egypt).

Although normally a material like *bronze* wouldn't be set off with a comma, you **could** put a comma between *Egyptian* and *bronze* which may make the distinction clearer:

> Archeologists discovered a unique, long, broken, ancient Egyptian, bronze spear from 5000 years ago.
>
> Archeologists discovered a unique, long, broken, ancient, Egyptian, bronze spear from 5000 years ago.

If you want "ancient Egyptian" to be treated as a single attribute, don't use a comma there.

Comment: Yes; the 'clarification / partitioning' use of the comma is a high-ranking usage. I'm not sure how all the different uses marry up. Rephrasing is a useful tool.

Comment: Now this has me wondering to myself—suppose we do intend "ancient Egyptian" to be a phrase; we could say "an ancient Egyptian bronze spear" with no commas needed, and I suppose "a broken ancient Egyptian bronze spear," and we have "spear" modified by at least three things without need for commas, but any more would require them. What's different here? I suppose it has something to do with restrictive identifiers (a "bronze spear" is a thing, a different thing than an iron spear) vs mere descriptors... but I'm having trouble putting my finger on it.

Comment: @AndyBonner Yes; it's the order. *A unique broken ancient Egyptian long bronze spear* would (in my view) **need** no commas even though a couple could be added easily; putting *long* where it is does need a comma to differentiate from *long-broken* -- broken for a long time.

Answer (score -2):

Ancient is the last word of the list, so you do not need a comma after 'ancient'. If you add a comma after 'ancient', "Egpytian bronze ...." will be part of that list and not a separate clause.

"A small, white, beautiful, cat is sitting there."

"A small, white, beautiful," is a dependent clause and does not make any sense, it is just a list. It is implying that the OP wrote the list and then suddenly changed his mind and started talking about some cat.

Comment: That is not what a [comma splice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) is.

Comment: @psmears yes, sorry I made a mistake there but the other explanation is correct.

Comment: Clauses usually contain verbs. You may find our sister site, ELL, more appropriate.